# How do I publish ASP.NET MVC3 application to azure using "Publish -> "Web Deploy"? (getting error: Web Deployment task failed)

Tags: msdeploy, azure-deployment, web-publishing, msbuild-wpp

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy to azure using "Publish" from my MVC project. I checked Web Management Service and Web Deployment Agent Service and there are both running. Credentials I'm using are valid since I get access to server instance through remote desktop

I've also checked values for the properties VS filled for me on the "Publish Web" dialog and they are correct:

Service Url: https://***.cloudapp.net:8172/MsDeploy.axd (where *** is my hosted service ID)

Site/Application: NLSubscriber.Web_IN_0_Web

> Error 66  Web deployment task failed.(Could not connect to the destination computer ("***.cloudapp.net"). On the destination computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("The Web Management Service") is started.)
>   This error indicates that you cannot connect to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network settings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and the appropriate services have been started on the server.
>   Error details:
>   Could not connect to the destination computer ("***.cloudapp.net"). On the destination computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("The Web Management Service") is started.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172
>   0 0  NLSubscriber.Web

- I've checked that the service url is reachable (and not blocked by
  the firewall), by directly accessing it through my browser typing
  just the same address VS is showing and after warning me about the
  not trusted certificated, it prompted me for user/password, which I
  provided and accessed it with no problem at all.
- I've opened Remote Desktop and checked site name from IIS manager,
  which is the same as pre-inputted by VS: NLSubscriber.Web_IN_0_Web.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Arwind has solved this issue on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/dfe98f28-b211-4124-a505-0c664f48b3e5/
Please check the link and see whether it helps.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.